# ereg_replace - string with forward slash

Tags: php

I have code like this:

```
<?php
    $first = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> TEST MESSAGE';
    echo ereg_replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "UPSS", $first);
?>
```

It doesn't work. I would like to get: 'UPSS TEST MESSAGE'

What did I wrong?

Comment: Ereg is deprecated. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php (big red box :) )

Comment: As @VladPreda says, do not use `ereg_replace()`. It is deprecated. Use `preg_replace()` instead. Having said that, in this case, it looks like you just want to replace a simple string, without any complex expressions, so I would say that `str_replace()` is better. In the regex replace functions, you'd need to escape the question marks and other characters with special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, several things here:

## 1st problem

You're declaring `$first` with `'` instead of `"`'s, yet you're escaping your double quotes, which means you'll end up with a litteral string of `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> TEST MESSAGE` (with backslashes).

```
$first = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> TEST MESSAGE';
//       ^              ^    ^           ^      ^                ^
// You don't need to escape " when using ' to create the string.
```

Instead either do

```
$first = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> TEST MESSAGE";
//       ^              ^    ^           ^      ^                ^
// We escape because we've used " to create the string
```

or

```
$first = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> TEST MESSAGE';
//       ^              ^   ^          ^     ^               ^
// We do not escape, because we used ' to create the string, and therefore only need to escape '.
```

would be correct

## 2nd problem

**You're using `ereg_replace`. Why? First of all, it's used for regex, which you don't seem to be using any of, secondly it's been deprecated for a long time, thirdly you're not feeding it regex.** You're also specifying the replacement with `"`'s, which means that you're replacing the string WITHOUT backslashes, and therefore it can't find a match (remember that `\"` is not the same as `"`). If you want to use regex now, look at [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), however you want to use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead, looking at your problem:

```
echo str_replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>', 'UPSS', $first);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use str_replace().
If you have aims to parse content, you should use XPath library.